# In Backbone, how do I have an after_render() on all views?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I am maintaining a javascript application and I would like there to be a jquery function invoked on pretty much every view. It would go something like this:

```
SomeView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend

  initialize: ->
    @on( 'render', @after_render )

  after_render: ->
    this.$el.fadeOut().fadeIn()
```

Clearly there is a better way to do this than have an after_render() in each view? What is the better way to do it? If you can give an answer that includes jasmine tests, I'll <3 you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own base view class and put your afterRender code in it. When you create a view, inherit from this class.

```
var MyApp.ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    afterRender: function() {
        // This will be called after rendering every inheriting view.
    }
});

var SpecificItemView = MyApp.ItemView.extend({
    // this view will automatically inherit the afterRender code.
});
```

In general, it seems to be considered good practice to define your own base views for all 3 view types. It will enable you to easily add global functionality later.

Answer (score 2):

The event you are looking for is onDomRefresh.  See here for the documentation:
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#view-domrefresh--ondomrefresh-event

Comment: This is the right answer. `onDomRefresh` is exactly what the OP wants.  No reason to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common pattern used across all Backbone frameworks, normally they have a render method which in turn calls  beforeRender, renderTemplate and afterRender methods.

```
render:function(){
   this.beforeRender();
   this.renderTemplate();// method names are just indicative
   this.afterRender();
   return this;
}
```

In your Base view you can have these methods to be empty functions, and implement them wherever you want it. Not sure this answer applies to Marionette

Answer (score 0):

Combining thibaut's and Robert Levy's answer, the correct solution would be:

```
var baseView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    onDomRefresh: function() {
        // This will be triggered after the view has been rendered, has been shown in the DOM via a Marionette.Region, and has been re-rendered
        // if you want to manipulate the dom element of the view, access it via this.$el or this.$('#some-child-selector')
    }
});

var SpecificItemView = baseView.extend({
    // this view will automatically inherit the onDomRefresh code.
});
```